# When testing Promises with Mocha, how can I print the full stack trace when an error occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, mocha.js

Suppose I have a small spec like:

```
describe("feature", () => {
  it("does stuff", () => {
    return myPromiseBasedFn().then(result => {
      expect(result).to.eql(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Currently, when the promise is rejected, I just see the error message. For example:

```
12 passing (88ms)
1 failing

1) feature does stuff:
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
```

How can I make mocha print the full stack trace of this error? For example, I'd like to see

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
    at SomeFunc (code/file.js:12:32)
    at code/base.js:49:24
```

Comment: Mocha seems to provide me with just enough stack trace to trace the issue (up to the `it` that's calling the breaking code), but it may depend on the call stack. You can try adding `--full-trace` to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

From this blog post: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/stack-traces-for-promises-in-node-js-46bf5f490fe4

You can use:

```
global.Promise = require("bluebird");
```

And then set:

```
BLUEBIRD_LONG_STACK_TRACES=1
```

When running tests to get complete stack traces:

```
BLUEBIRD_LONG_STACK_TRACES=1 mocha …
```

This works with Typescript, and if you're using `cls-hooked`, you also need to include:

```
let cls = require('cls-hooked');
let clsNamespace = cls.createNamespace('some-namespace')
let clsBluebird = require('cls-bluebird')
let Promise = require('bluebird')
clsBluebird(clsNamespace, Promise)
```